# estoy ocupando ionic + angular pero no me cargan las imágenes ¿Que puedo hacer?

Tags: android, android-studio, nodejs, angular, ionic-framework

las imágenes cargan en el buscador al ejecutar "ionic serve" pero al tratar de abrir la aplicación por AndroidStudio o desde mi celular no cargan[image: así es como aparece]

investigue por skackoverflow pero no me funciono ninguna de las soluciones
además verifique que la ruta estuviera bien y tampoco es eso

algunas de las cosas que ocupe para este proyecto fue ionic, angular, nodejs y capacitor